# Command only working when put directly in command prompt, not in batch file

Tags: windows-server-2008, command-line-interface, batch-file, windows-sbs-2011, wake-on-lan

On my SBS 2011 I have a batch file called *wakeup-nas.bat*, with the following contents:

```
wol.exe 5475e0d59ffa
```

wol.exe is an executable for sending wake on lan packets. It is in the same directory as the batch file.

Strangely the command is only working when I write it directly in the command prompt. When I open the batch file nothing happens, although I see the output from wol.exe that the packet has successfully been sent.

I also have tried to open the batch file "as administrator" with no success either.

Comment: does it work if you specify the full path to it?

Comment: A couple of possibilities: Put a `pause` at the end off your batch file and let it hang there for a while. Does the command still fail? (Can you post the output?) Also, put a `set` at the beginning of the batch file and compare it with the output of `set` in a command prompt. There may be some context differences you can spot.

Comment: Is WOL.exe in your path or the working directory of the batch file? I'm guessing not.

Comment: wol.exe and the batch file are in the same directory

Answer (score 2):

Try putting the full path to wol.exe. Also try putting an echo statement on your batch file. That might help.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm. I don't really know why, but it's working now with the batch file too, even without "run as administrator". 
May have something to do with the network card drivers I updated yesterday.